# override messagebox and add icons to the default buttons

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Does anyone know here how to override the messagebox to put icons for the buttons? i.e: check icon for YES/OK, cross button for NO, etc.

I've tried to override the `makeButton` function of `Ext.window.MessageBox` but it doesn't seem to work and doesn't even hit the `debugger`:

```
Ext.override(Ext.window.MessageBox, {
    makeButton: function (btnIdx) {
        debugger;
        var btnId = this.buttonIds[btnIdx];
        return new Ext.button.Button({
            handler: this.btnCallback,
            itemId: btnId,
            scope: this,
            text: this.buttonText[btnId],
            minWidth: 75,
            iconCls: ['check', 'no', 'cancel', 'blah'][btnId]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @scebotari66 have stated, `Ext.Msg` and `Ext.MessageBox` are singletons of `Ext.window.MessageBox`. So when you override `Ext.window.MessageBox.makeButton`, this will have no effect if you are using the singletons for this class.

However, there is a way to apply your overrides to `Ext.window.MessageBox` to the singleton. Guess how.

(*drumroll*)

**tantantanan!**

`Ext.MessageBox = Ext.Msg = new Ext.window.MessageBox();`

Yep, that's correct. You just need to re-assign the singleton after your override.

So:

```
Ext.override(Ext.window.MessageBox, {
    makeButton: function (btnIdx) {
        var btnId = this.buttonIds[btnIdx];
        return new Ext.button.Button({
            handler: this.btnCallback,
            itemId: btnId,
            scope: this,
            text: this.buttonText[btnId],
            iconCls: ['okbutton', 'yesbutton', 'closebutton', 'cancelbutton'][btnIdx],
            minWidth: 75 //or you can also remove this to make the icons close to the label
        });
    }
});
//re-assign singleton to apply overrides
Ext.MessageBox = Ext.Msg = new Ext.window.MessageBox();
```

Next time you call `Ext.Msg.alert()`, your icons are now showing too.

I hope you find this helpful.

**NOTE:** The `iconCls` config should be in the order `[ok, yes, no, cancel]`

Comment: couldnt have seen it either if you havent answered. :) you own 80% of the credit :D

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the source code, the `makeButton` method is called from  [initComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/source/MessageBox.html#Ext-window-MessageBox-method-initComponent) of `Ext.window.MessageBox`.

I assume that you are using the `Ext.MessageBox` (or `Ext.Msg`) singleton instance for displaying message boxes. This instance is created in the callback function immediately after the `Ext.window.MessageBox` is created (check the third argument from [Ext.define](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext-method-define)). This also means that it happens before your override.

So you can directly override the buttons of the singleton instance like so:

```
Ext.Msg.msgButtons.ok.setIconCls(okBtnCls);
Ext.Msg.msgButtons.yes.setIconCls(yesBtnCls);
Ext.Msg.msgButtons.no.setIconCls(noBtnCls);
Ext.Msg.msgButtons.cancel.setIconCls(cancelBtnCls);
```

You can also rely on your `makeButton` override if you will show message boxes by creating a new instance of the class:

```
var myMsg = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {
    closeAction: 'destroy'
}).show({
    title: 'Custom MessageBox Instance',
    message: 'I can exist along with Ext.Msg'
});
```

Comment: I think the `makeButton` override will do.. see my answer